# Android Google Plus Circles Birthday

Tags: android, google-plus

I've been searching for a good explanation on why I can't gather birthdays or taglines from people in a user's circle on Google Plus.  I've played with the OAuth 2.0 Playground and retrieved birthday and tagline info from people in my circles who have their security set to "visible to circles" but I can't figure out why this isn't available in the Google+ API for Android.

The user is logged in to Google Plus using an ApiClient:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(GatherGoogle.this)
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.addApi(Plus.API, null)
.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
.build();
```

Then in onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) method, after gathering the current user's info to populate a header, I call for the PeopleApi to load visible connections:

```
Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);
```

This calls the onResult(LoadPeopleResult peopleData) method which is supposed to return a list of People, which it does.  It also gives me their display name, id, thumbnail, etc... all the basic profile info typical.  I'm curious what I need to do to get the next level of info from a persons profile.  If I go online to my Google+ account, I can click through people in my circles and see their birthdays and taglines, and playing with the Playground, I can retrieve that information... I just can't figure out how to implement what is needed to in my Android app.

Are there other scopes I need to add? What are they and where are they documented?  Is there a separate call I make to the People API? I would be fine making GET calls and parsing through JSON data, but I wanted to know what the best way, if any, would be to go about this without too much trouble.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Any luck figuring this out? I'm having the same issue, birthday is always returned as null.

Answer (score 0):

On your Google+ Profile -> About -> Basic Information -> Edit

You Should Change the Circles to ***"Public"*** and mark ***"Show birthday year"***

Result ***"YYYY-MM-DD"***

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this method to get bday data: load(GoogleApiClient, String...)

Read this:
public abstract PendingResult loadVisible (GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, String pageToken)

Loads the list of visible people in the user's circles. For more information, see: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list.

Each Person will contain the id, displayName, image, objectType, and url fields populated. To retrieve additional profile data, use the load(GoogleApiClient, String...) method.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/People.html

Comment: `PendingResult` status for `load` is `CommonStatusCodes.NETWORK_ERROR`. Any clues?